# WiFi option disappeared after installing updates in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10

This morning I installed some of the updates for Ubuntu 12.10 and my WiFi has disappeared.

This is the output for `rfkill list all`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

You can see that there is not even an option for wireless. I also tried:

`sudo lshw -c network`

```
  *-network NO RECLAMADO  
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       versión: 00
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: ioport:e000(size=256) memoria:f7d00000-f7d03fff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0.2
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.2
       nombre lógico: eth0
       versión: 06
       serie: 00:90:f5:e2:f7:05
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 100Mbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 ip=192.168.1.38 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:41 ioport:d000(size=256) memoria:f0004000-f0004fff memoria:f0000000-f0003fff
```

The laptop is an Airis Praxis N1204 32 bits.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited as I've been trying to fix it since 9 am
Thanks for the replies so far. I have tried the two solutions suggested below, but unfortunately the problem persists.

This is the output from `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5286 (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: include `lspci` also. If you have installed driver manually (not from `addtional driver` tab of software center) you need to do it again

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my laptop. I have run these commands and afther that it worked:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: 3 years later, and this still worked for me on 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Try these following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```